# On successful ajax, create a dropdown select from another table with preselected option value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

For an ‘Edit’ modal, I initiate an `ajax` call to the `php` script named `getSelectedMember.php` that bring the information from the table `items` (Table 2).
[image: tabels]

```
<?php 
   require_once 'db_connect.php';  

   $memberId = $_POST['member_id']; 

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemID = $memberId";
   $query = $connect->query($sql);
   $result = $query->fetch_assoc();

   echo json_encode($result);
?>
```

This `formulation_fk` is in the table `items` a value of a select option from another table named `formulation` (Table 1).

This is code of 'edit.php' :

```
<form action=" " method="POST">
   <div>
      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text"><br>
   </div>
   <div>
      <label>Formulation</label>
      <select id="editFormulation">
      </select>
   </div>
   <button type = "submit">Save changes</button>
</form>
```

My question is while updating a single item, how can I pass the `select` options from the `formulation` table in my edit form where the select `option value` will be the `formulation_fk` from the table `items`?

And this is my `ajax` call:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'getSelectedMember.php',
  type: 'post',
  data: {
    member_id: itemID
  },
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {
    $("#editName").val(response.name);
    $("#editFormulation").val(response.formulation_fk);
    $(".editMemberModal").append( ? ? ? ? ? ? )
  }
});
```

For clarification of my question, let's think that to edit `Water`, the action flow would be like this:

1. Click the edit button for ‘Water’.
2. Ajax call to `getSelectedMember.php` to get the `name` (Water) and
   `formulation_fk` (1).
3. On response, Name field will output ‘Water’
   and Formulation filed will output a dropdown `select` from
   `formulation` table where `option value = “1”`

Something like this image below.
[image: Result]

I have been trying to solve it for a while but I'll really appreciate any suggestion or expert help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no `id="editName` or `id="editFormulation"` in the HTML of `edit.php`.

Comment: fixed the "" and query error. And actually, I'm focusing on the `select` part here. So, for simplicity of the question, I've ignored the `Name` section. Thanks. @Barmar

Comment: I still don't see any of the IDs that you're updating in the AJAX success function. What is that supposed to be updating?

Comment: Should `id="newFormulation"` be `id="editFormulation"`? That `<select>` doesn't have any options, so setting its value won't have any effect.

Comment: You are right. And please forget the update call. I'm here trying to get the answer how can I populate the select options from the `formulation` table while pre selecting the option value of the item from the value of `formulation_fk` from table `items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP code needs to return an array of all the formulations, in addition to the `formulation_fk` from the `items` table.

```
$memberId = $_POST['member_id']; 

$sql = "SELECT * FROM items WHERE itemID = $memberId";
$query = $connect->query($sql);
$result = $query->fetch_assoc();

$sql = "SELECT * FROM formulation";
$query = $connect->query($sql);
$formulations = array();
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $formulations[] = $row;
}
$result['formulations'] = $formulations;

echo json_encode($result);
```

Then the AJAX code can fill in the `<select>` before setting its value.

```
success: function(response) {
    $("#editFormulation").empty(); // Clear out previous value
    $.each(response.formulations, function() {
        $("#editFormulation").append($("<option>", {
            value: this.formulationID,
            text: this.formulation_name
        }));
    });
    $("#editFormulation").val(response.valuation_fk);
    $("#editName").val(response.name);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response but it does not return any option in the drop-down. Any suggestion why this might be happening?

Comment: Still nothing is returning from the after the call.

Comment: What do you see in `console.log(response.formulations)`?

Comment: It is working perfectly now. It was my mistake. Your code is perfectly alright. Thanks a lot for your effort.  :)